# how to display output in table from file using flask

Tags: python, flask

hi i need to display my output on flask web page in table form i get output in this format right now where `wraith` is my PC name `connected / disconnected` is `status` and `IP`. I Save client output in `logs.log` file then i read the file and display it on web page like this.

`wraith Connected USB from IP: 127.0.0.1`

`wraith Disconnected USB from IP: 127.0.0.1`

`wraith Connected USB from IP: 127.0.0.1`

I need to display this output in table formate like this

`CLIENT`          `IP`         `STATUS`

wraith   127.0.0.1        connected

wraith   127.0.0.1        disconnected

like this example

[image]

this is my client code

```
import requests
import subprocess, string, time
import os

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
name = os.uname()[1]

def on_device_add():
    requests.post(f'{url}/device_add?name={name}')
def on_device_remove():
    requests.post(f'{url}/device_remove?name={name}')

def detect_device(previous):
    total = subprocess.run('lsblk | grep disk | wc -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    time.sleep(3)

    # if condition if new device add
    if total > previous:
        on_device_add()
    # if no new device add or remove
    elif total == previous:
        detect_device(previous)
    # if device remove
    else:
        on_device_remove()
    # Infinite loop to keep client running.


while True:
    detect_device(subprocess.run(' lsblk | grep disk | wc -l', shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)
```

this is my flask app

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/device_add", methods=['POST'])
def device_add():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    with open('logs.log', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{name} Connected USB from IP: {request.remote_addr}\n')
    return 'ok'

@app.route("/device_remove", methods=['POST'])
def device_remove():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    with open('logs.log', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{name} Disconnected USB from IP: {request.remote_addr}\n')

    return 'ok'


@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def device_list():
    with open('logs.log', 'r') as f:
        return ''.join(f'<div>{line}</div>' for line in f.readlines())
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Does the code not work correctly? Do you get errors?

Comment: i need to display the output in table form like i mention my output it is in straight line i need to read file and display it in form of table

Comment: `return ''.join(f'<div>{line}</div><br>' for line in f.readlines())`?

Comment: yes it only print whole file line by line not in table formate

Comment: Because you haven't given any HTML to put it in a table. Did you note that in my last comment I put a line break at the end? That won't be a table, but it should give you new lines

Comment: it only add break between lines , i need to display in table formate

Comment: like 3 columns name `client` `ip` `status`

Comment: So you keep saying. And as I keep saying, you need to write HTML to make the table. You should attempt doing that; there are plenty of tutorials on how to build tables and pass data from flask

Comment: ok thank you i will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually provide some HTML to get what you want. Normally you'd have a separate HTML template inside a "templates" directory and you'd use `render_template`. In this case, I've built the template as a string inside the python script just to demo, but this is not sustainable in actual projects.

The syntax for looping the data rows and inserting individual points is based on [Jinja2](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/)

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)


TABLE_TEMPLATE = """
<style>
   table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   }
</style>
<table style="width: 100%">
   <thead>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>IP</th>
      <th>Status</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for row in data %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{ row.client }}</td>
         <td>{{ row.ip }}</td>
         <td>{{ row.status }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
"""

@app.route("/device_add", methods=['POST'])
def device_add():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    with open('logs.log', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{name} Connected USB from IP: {request.remote_addr}\n')
    return 'ok'

@app.route("/device_remove", methods=['POST'])
def device_remove():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    with open('logs.log', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{name} Disconnected USB from IP: {request.remote_addr}\n')

    return 'ok'


@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def device_list():
    keys = ['client', 'ip', 'status']
    data = []
    with open('logs.log', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            row = line.split()
            data.append(dict(zip(keys, [row[0], row[-1], row[1]])))
            
    return render_template_string(TABLE_TEMPLATE,
                                  data=data)
```